# AngularJS kills my Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have to bother you again with a question, resulting from my lack of JS-Experience ;)...

I've got a template using a javascript function for a sidebar, which should show a sub-menu when clicked on a parent item.
If i hardcode the sidebar everything works fine.

*But what i **really want** is to dynamically build that menu using angularJS' ng-repeat.*
When i try this, the menu doesn't collapse anymore.

Here is an example to rebuid the problem (which i hopefully didn't fuck up by cleaning the irrelevant code around, for rebuilding the example):

---

So first of all we've got the following file-structure:

1. **assets**

   - **angularjs**

     - angular.min.js
   - **bootstrap**

     - [[You find that standard bootstrap 3.0.3 structure here (css, fonts, js)]](http://getbootstrap.com/)
   - **font-awesome**

     - [[You find that standard font-awesome structure here]](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)
   - **jquery**

     - jquery.js (v.1.10.2)
2. **public**

   - **js**

     - template.js
3. **views**

   - index.html
   - de-DE.json

---

index.html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app id="ng-app" ng-controller="languageKey">

<head>
    <title>{{ lg.website }}</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style>
        #main-nav .sub-nav {
            display: none;
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 1em 0;
            padding-left: 25px;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            border-bottom: none;
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <ul class="open-active" id="main-nav">

                <li class="dropdown" ng-repeat="lang in lg.sidebar.menuItems">
                    <a href="javascript:;">
                        <i class="fa fa-{{ lang.icon }}"></i>
                        {{ lang.title }}
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <li ng-repeat="sub in lang.subItems">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-{{ sub.icon }}"></i>
                                {{ sub.title }}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:;">
                        <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>
                        Example Pages
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="./page-profile.html">
                                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                Profile
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="./page-invoice.html">
                                <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
                                Invoice
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <script src="../assets/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/js/template.js"></script>
    <script>
        function languageKey($scope, $http)
        {
           $http({method: 'POST', url: 'de-DE.json'}).success(function(data)
           {
               $scope.lg = data; //response Data
           });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

de-DE.json looks like:

```
{
    "website":"Website Name",
    "sidebar": {
        "menuItems": [
            {
                "title":"Dashboard",
                "icon":"dashboard"
            },
            {
                "title":"Musik verwalten",
                "icon":"file-text",
                "subItems": [
                    {
                        "title": "Songs hochladen",
                        "icon": "user"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Diskografie",
                        "icon": "money"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Statistik",
                        "icon": "dollar"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "title":"Einstellungen",
                "icon":"tasks",
                "subItems": [
                    {
                        "title": "Benutzer",
                        "icon": "location-arrow"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Anfragen",
                        "icon": "magic"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Einstellungen",
                        "icon": "check"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Sprachen",
                        "icon": "check"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Neuigkeiten",
                        "icon": "check"
                    }

                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

---

finally the template.js:

```
var App = function () {
    "use strict";

    var chartColors = ['#e5412d', '#f0ad4e', '#444', '#888','#555','#999','#bbb','#ccc','#eee'];

    return { init: init, chartColors: chartColors, debounce: debounce };

    function init () {
        initLayout ();      
    }

    function initLayout () {
        $('#site-logo').prependTo ('#wrapper');
        $('html').removeClass ('no-js');

        Nav.init ();    

        $('body').on('touchstart.dropdown', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) { 
            e.stopPropagation(); 
        });
    }

    function debounce (func, wait, immediate) {
        var timeout, args, context, timestamp, result;
        return function() {
            context = this;
            args = arguments;
            timestamp = new Date();

            var later = function() {
                var last = (new Date()) - timestamp;

                if (last < wait) {
                    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait - last);
                } else {
                    timeout = null;
                    if (!immediate) result = func.apply(context, args);
                }
            };

            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;

            if (!timeout) {
                timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
            }

            if (callNow) result = func.apply(context, args);
            return result;
        };
    }
}();



var Nav = function () {

    return { init: init };

    function init () {
        var mainnav = $('#main-nav'),
            openActive = mainnav.is ('.open-active'),
            navActive = mainnav.find ('> .active');

        mainnav.find ('> .dropdown > a').bind ('click', navClick);

        if (openActive && navActive.is ('.dropdown')) {         
            navActive.addClass ('opened').find ('.sub-nav').show ();
        }
    }

    function navClick (e) {
        e.preventDefault ();

        var li = $(this).parents ('li');        

        if (li.is ('.opened')) { 
            closeAll ();            
        } else { 
            closeAll ();
            li.addClass ('opened').find ('.sub-nav').slideDown ();          
        }
    }

    function closeAll () {  
        $('.sub-nav').slideUp ().parents ('li').removeClass ('opened');
    }
}();


$(function () {
    App.init ();
});
```

---

As you can see i've hardcoded the last item of the sidebar (Example Pages), and it should work. The part above doesn't.

I know this example is freaking long, but i didn't know how to reduce it in a way that lets you simply rebuild the problem.

Anyways, i hope that someone can help me out.

Best regards
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, your init functions happens before angular builds the DOM. You know how jQuery needs to wait for document ready to do most things? Well, imagine the document is just constnatly changing. That's what angular is. Your document is 100% dynamic. Your `navclick` function is not bound to anything in ng-repeat... because ng-repeat hasn't created anything yet.

It's pretty tricky to add angular to an existing javascript app. Easiest way to get this going is to remove your existing jQuery and try it all in Angular. That seems daunting at first, but it's probably pretty easy! Use ng-click to replace navclick, etc.